# ListView customization

Tags: android, listview

I have a list with RSS feed. If I write this:

```
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
        for (Message msg : messages){
            titles.add(msg.getDate());
            titles.add(msg.getTitle());
```

I get the title and the date in separate strings.

I tried to change it to:

```
titles.add(msg.getDate()+msg.getTitle());
```

but this returns date and titles with no space.

I would like to have date and below it the title, something like:

```
Thu 27 Jan 2011
Bla bla bla..
```

How could I do it? Also, may I have another text color or size in the date and other in the title?

Comment: Could it be possible to have two rows in every list item?and,in the first row it will be the title with 20px textSize and in the second the date with 14px size..thats i m looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach, although a little more complex, is to use a layout xml file to specify the layout of the row and an adapter to bind each specific piece of info of each message (like the date and title) to a specific widget in the row layout.

The reason this may be better is that this way is that:

- the layout info (stacking date over the message) stays in the XML and out of the code
- it also makes it easier to use more complex layouts in the future (how about showing the author too? categories?),
- it makes it easier to modify the layout in the future. and
- it allows you to use more complex widgets and widget features, like specifying a scrolling marque text view for when descriptions are long

This example uses `SimpleAdapter` to bind a `List` of `Map`ped data to the complex rows of a ListView.

http://www.vbsteven.be/blog/using-the-simpleadapter-with-a-listview-in-android/

```
// get messages from service
ArrayList smsMessages = service.getSmsCalls();

// initialize the List of Maps
List<map> list = new ArrayList<map>();

// iterate over all messages
// create a map for each message
// fill the map with data
for (Call c: smsMessages) {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("number", c.getTo());
    map.put("date", DateParser.getTimeString(c.getBegin()));
    map.put("price", "€ " + c.getPrice());
    list.add(map);
}

// the from array specifies which keys from the map
// we want to view in our ListView
String[] from = {"number", "date", "price"};

// the to array specifies the TextViews from the xml layout
// on which we want to display the values defined in the from array
int[] to = {R.id.callog_detail_sms_number, R.id.callog_detail_sms_date, R.id.callog_detail_sms_price};

// get a reference to the ListView
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.callog_detail_listview);

// create the adapter and assign it to the listview
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), list, R.layout.callog_detail_sms, from, to);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Unfortunately, the article doesn't show the layout xml, but its going to be similar to the next example below.  If you really only have 2 fields, a LinearLayout is fine.  More than 2 in a more complex layout, start looking at RelativeLayout:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip" 

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
titles.add(msg.getDate()+" "+msg.getTitle());
```

... or, if you want to have an ENTER between those two... you will have to wrap it in a HTML string:

```
titles.add(msg.getDate()+"<br/>"+msg.getTitle());
// and somewhere else, when you are going to draw it:
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(title.get(position)));
```

Comment: i m sorry but the second way its not working...any more idea please?

Comment: it prompts me to create local variable textview and position

Comment: OK dude... in my example, textView is whatever. It's not something you have to write exactly like that. I guess you set the values of your list manually inside your adapter (you didn't paste the code, so the only thing we can do is guess), so when you are setting the value you use `YOUR_TEXT_VIEW_HERE.setText(Html.fromHtml(title.get(position)));` or some variation of that code. The important part is the `Html.fromHtml` method.

Comment: of course i had changed the textview to textView01 as i have named it

Comment: Paste more code... I still don't understand what you are doing.